# Access argparse variables from external module

Tags: python, argparse

I have 4 modules:

- `entry_point.py`
- `utils.py`
- `runner.py`
- `client.py`

I use `argparse` in `utils.py` and I want to be able to retrieve the value of one of those arguments in `client.py`.

- Entry point module (the one that gets called from console):

  ```
  import utils
  def main():
      console_args = utils.parse_arguments() # Get command-line arguments
      runner.run(console_args) # The main function in the program

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
  ```
- `utils.py` module:

  ```
  def parse_arguments():
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
      parser.add_argument(
          # Several arguments, one of which should be 'url'
      )
      return parser.parse_args()
  ```
- `runner.py` module:

  ```
  import client

  def run(arguments):
      user = User.new(arguments.user_id)
      client.get_user_info(user)
  ```
- `client.py` module:

  ```
  def get_user_info(user):
      url = _compose_url('user_status')
      resp = requests.post(url, data=user.id)

  def _compose_url(method):
      # TODO: get base_url from console arguments
      # base_url = ?
      return base_url + str(method)
  ```

I don't want to pass `url` as a parameter to `client.get_user_info()` because I don't think it would be good to have it as a parameter for that function.

So I would like to be able to retrieve the argparse arguments I got from `utils.parse_arguments()` directly. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You could make the arguments a module (`entry_point` or `utils`) wide variable (set to `None` until the arguments are parsed), and import inside `_compose_url`. But that may feel somewhat obscure. Alternatively, create a one-off wrapper function with a `url` parameter around `get_user_info`. Or rethink your function(s), since apparently `get_user_info` *does* require a `base_url`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like the suggestion my comment and Mike Müller's answer, the below code sets a module-level variable.
To prevent argument parsing upon import, however, I set the variable only once `parse_arguments` is called. Since the variable is set to `None` before that happens, I also only import the variable when needed.
This way, `parse_arguments` is only run when you call it, not when you import the module. It is probably not needed in your specific case, but can be convenient when e.g. a module like `utils` is used in a package.

`utils.py`:

```
CONSOLE_ARGUMENTS = None

def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        # Several arguments, one of which should be 'url'
    )
     parser.parse_args()
    global CONSOLE_ARGUMENTS
    CONSOLE_ARGUMENTS = parser.parse_args()
    return CONSOLE_ARGUMENTS
```

`client.py`:

```
def _compose_url(method):
    from .utils import CONSOLE_ARGUMENTS
    base_url = CONSOLE_ARGUMENTS.base_url
    return base_url + str(method)
```

Answer (score 5):

Make a new module `console_args.py`:

```
"""
Parsing of command line arguments.

No other functionality should be added to this module.
The typically usage is:

>>> from console_args import CONSOLE_ARGS 
"""

def _parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        # Several arguments, one of which should be 'url'
    )
    return parser.parse_args()

CONSOLE_ARGS =  _parse_arguments()

# optional: delete function after use to prevent calling from other place
del _parse_arguments
```

Now you use it in all modules:

```
from console_args import CONSOLE_ARGS
```

The function `_parse_arguments()` will be executed only once.
Modules in Python are singletons, i.e. they will only executed at the first import.
Each subsequent import will get a module object without doing the whole import procedure, that executes all module level code, again.

The underscore in `_parse_arguments()`indicates that this function is not supposed to be used outside the module `console_args.py`.
Deleting `_parse_arguments` after it was called will prevent any other call of `_parse_arguments()` during the run time of the program (as long as no reload tricks are applied).

Comment: This way, the argument parsing is done upon import. That may not be what you want all the time.

Comment: @Evert could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @KurtBourbaki The moment you run `import utils` or similar, `_parse_arguments()` is also ran. Usually, in a script, that's ok, but if you ever want to just import the `utils` module without parsing any arguments, that may give unexpected results.

Comment: @Evert Just don't put anything else in `utils.py` and use it only for parsing. Maybe call it `console_args.py` and make clear that is only purpose is parsing the  command line argsuments.

Comment: @MikeMüller Indeed, but the name `utils.py` suggests there is more than just argument parsing in that module. I instead often have a module named `args.py` just for argument parsing. Besides, my comment is more about the generic case, not the specific case here. Hence my answer as an alternative which may be useful in other cases.

Comment: Changed the name of the module and added a docstring that makes the intention of this module clear.